# What chemical reaction happens on worn out metal handles?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I randomly came across a picture of this. It's the comparison between right handed and left handed people. As more people use the door handle, the metal becomes more faded and turns gold color. What is this gold color underneath and why does friction between your fingers and the door handle cause this reaction?

[image]

Comment: Consider using more particular titles, this one is too general, being rather a click bait. If you was a writer, you would not probably name your book "What is this story about ?".

Comment: I have changed the title to be little more descriptive. Feel free to modify it if you udo not like it.

Comment: @Poutnik I probably wouldn't even use "chemical reaction" to describe grinding a metal surface. The question is pretty much the same as to why the chopped water melon being green from outside has red-colored cuts. Not much chemistry to begin with, really.

Comment: @andselisk I fully agree with you. But I have intentionally formulated it rather from POV of the OP, wondering about chemical reactions, than from my POV, backup up by some knowledge or experience.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a brass ( a class of alloys, containing mostly copper and zinc, being golden-like ), which surface was covered by protective plating , possibly by chrome or nickel(*). It was probably worn out mechanically and/or by corrosion due acidic sweat.

(*)Nickel plating could be worn out easier than hard and resistant chrome.

Comment: I understand nickel plate is more common on many decorative items today  because of lower "shine" compared to chrome.

Comment: @blacksmith37  Could be. I am no specialist here.  But I know Ni plating of Cu goes well by both galvanic and chemical way. I also remember watching Canadian documentary serie about airplane disasters, where in 1 episode the disaster cause was the worn out and snapped stainless steel string, because contained nickel caused faster mechanical wearing out than pilot expected. Routine controls require since than more frequent checks of stainless steel strings in small aircrafts. It was more corrosion resistent for maritime usage, but mechanically more vulnerable.

Comment: I watch most similar documentaries ; all produced by people who do not know the technology. Aircraft cables are cold drawn stainless ( 301, 302, 304 )  so an affect of nickel makes no sense,  The cables should be in a relatively dry corrosion free environment inside the aircraft.

Comment: @blacksmith37 That specific use was about a small pacific inter-island jumper, so corrosion was an issue, or at least that was reported as the reason why the usual material was not used. It was a naked string, not a cable, if cable means some isolation, which was moving along some guiders, what was mechanically wearing it out until the break.  301 has 6-8 % of Ni, 302 8-10%, 304  8-10.5% ( https://www.meadmetals.com/metal-products/stainless-steel/physical-chemical-properties). What do you mean by "So effect of nickel makes no sense ?"

Comment: Maybe a language difference ; steels are not made as "strings"  , steel comes a single wire, or multiple wires braded into cables.  Aircraft use cables so they have redundancy,  then even with a few individual wires broken the cable can still function. Nickel is homogeneously distributed in austenitic SS , so there can be no" failure of nickel". Cold worked 18-8 type stainless would be a poor choice of material for maritime corrosion.  As I said ,the people that produce these shows do not understand the technology.

Comment: OK, cables then, I am not native and may not know the jargon. Czech distinguish EN cable as CZ lano , while CZ "kabel" means cable or any similar encapsuled in mechanical/electrical isolation, usually plastic. Sure multiwire cable has redundancy, but as known from bicycle, it can rupture anyway.

Comment: It was meant steel alloy containing nickel has increased mechanical wearing out rate. It was not show, it was based on real disaster investigations.

Comment: BTW, I have noticed since I started use stainless steel cables for bicycle gearing and brakes, I need to change them more often, compared to non stainless steel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116170/discussion-between-poutnik-and-blacksmith37).